# How to Resolve Error:(2, 0) Cannot convert URL Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar

i import `com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker` with `aar` file to my project but after gradle sync i see this error and i cant resolve this :(

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyEPX.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can see on [Github](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker) how to import this library properly.

This library is not released in Maven Central, but instead you can use JitPack

add remote maven url in allprojects.repositories

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

then add a library dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
    }
```

Comment: at the first i use this way and i cant resolve this error : Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13